Using Sqlite JDBC driver in bazel project
Sqlite-jbcb tutorial starts with downloading the jar file. Is there a way to add it to bazel project? Searched around and only find this on adding it to gradle project.

You can use rules_jvm_external
And fetch the maven dependency:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

